# Use phone's built-in Visual Voicemail on T-Mobile USA?

Tags: voicemail, t-mobile

Is there any way to get Visual Voicemail working using the Phone (dialer) app on T-Mobile in the USA?

I have two open-market phones - one a factory unlocked handset from China (Unihertz Titan) running Android 9, the other a formerly-locked (to Telstra, if that matters) Galaxy S10+ running Android 10 - and neither can access visual voicemail through their in-box Phone apps. I've never had this problem before, with older Androids (back around the Android 4 days) or with the Windows phones I used until EoL (everything from WP7.x through W10M, VVM worked out of the box perfectly).

T-Mobile has a VVM app on the Play store, but even aside from the inconvenience of needing a separate app for what all my previous phones had integrated, it is... bad. It's rated 2.5 stars, and it earns it (not all voicemails showing up, generally clunky and unreliable).

I've been on the phone with T-Mobile, Samsung, and even Telstra; none could help. On the Titan, the VVM screen always says "Visual voicemail is not activated yet, please try again later". On the S10+, the VVM toglle is just outright missing from the built-in phone app.

I haven't rooted either phone, and they're both running stock ROMs. I have ADB installed, if that's needed.

Comment: Sorry, I don't have experience with T-Mobile nor VVM, but looks like [there are many who have the same problem with T-Mobile's VVM](https://support.google.com/pixelphone/thread/21872083)

Comment: Thanks @AndrewT. I'd seen some discussion of the problem but it was older than that thread. Unfortunately I've already tried the things it mentioned (installing and uninstalling the TMo VVM app, calling the operator and manufacturer) but like others mentioned it didn't help me. :-(  Very frustrating, coming from a tiny market share and long-deprecated OS where this feature worked perfectly to the most common mobile OS on the planet and a flagship device, and finding it doesn't.